# Do different models of notebook have different levels of mSATA storage capacity?

Tags: msata

I’m thinking of getting the [Samsung SSD 840 EVO mSATA](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/uk/html/ssd840evo/overview_mSATA.html) for my XMG notebook. Are there any limitations on mSATA memory size regarding different motherboards? Or can I put any mSATA III in my mSATA III port regardless of size?

Also while looking at [Tesco](http://www.tesco.com)’s online version it’s listed as 2.5 inch bay but clearly has mSATA connection type? Probably a mistake but one causing doubt since given dimensions are greater than other mSATA cards I’ve seen.

Comment: Many laptops have both an mSATA slot and a 2.5" SATA slot. What model exactly is yours?

Comment: (@Jake, great edit!)

Answer (score 1):

[mSATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) is a **Serial ATA International Organization** standard.  Your only concern should be to verify the physical dimensions of the drive will fit in your device as the standard only covers the connector itself.

> Mini-SATA (abbreviated as mSATA), which is distinct from the micro
>   connector, was announced by the Serial ATA International Organization
>   on September 21, 2009.  Applications include netbooks, laptops and
>   other devices that require a solid-state drive in a small footprint.
>
> The connector is similar in appearance to a PCI Express Mini Card
>   interface, but is not electrically compatible; the data signals
>   (TX±/RX± SATA, PETn0 PETp0 PERn0 PERp0 PCI Express) need a connection
>   to the SATA host controller instead of the PCI Express host
>   controller.

This is what the device in question looks like.

[image]

You also need to verify your device actually has a mSATA connector.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29)